# Switch depending on a previous switch variable

Tags: java, android

I'm totally new to programming and I'm trying to just create a calculator of the day you're going to die(Obviuosly false). I have done the following switches that take data from user input such as questions as Do you smoke or are you male or female.
This is the code I have :

```
package as.as;

import as.as.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class myMenu extends Activity{
  protected static final float Die = 80;
  protected  float Gender;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView MensajeGender = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.age);
    final RadioGroup rggender = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);

    rggender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedIdGender) {
        switch(checkedIdGender){
          //male
          case 2131099655:
            double Gender = (Die*0.93);    
            MensajeGender.setText("" + Gender);
            break;
          //female
          case 2131099656:
            Gender =  (Die*1.04);
            MensajeGender.setText("" + Gender);
            break;
        }

        final RadioGroup rgsmoke = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        rgsmoke.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedIdSmoke) {
            switch(checkedIdSmoke){
              case 2131099660:
              double Smoke =  Gender*0.93;
              MensajeGender.setText("" + Smoke);
              break;
            case 2131099661:
              Smoke = Gender*1.04;    
              MensajeGender.setText(" " + Smoke);
              break;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };
}
```

EDIT(ADD QUESTION): What's wrong here?
EDIT2: If I get to finish this, how would you recommend me to learn to programm in android? A book or something?(Completely new to programming, even though i knew a bit of C++)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not asking something here but I think that you're struggling with code design...

---

*Edit*:
When you're starting with programming I would recommend to learn Java first. It will be really frustrating to struggle with android before you don't understand the basics of Java. I would search for Java console tutorials (there where pretty good ones when I started a couple of years ago ;-).

---

You can't react on radio button change individually because they depend on each other. So first of all I would suggest that you trigger a helper method (e.g. `updateDate()`) on checked state change).

Here's what the helper would do:

```
public void updateDate() {
    final TextView MensajeGender = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.age);
    final RadioGroup rggender = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
    final RadioGroup rgsmoke = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

    double date;

    // switch gender and calculate date
    // switch smoke and calculate date

    MensajeGender.setText(" " + date);
}
```

You can use [getCheckedRadioButtonId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29) to check the selected button. And would recommend to use text IDs instead hard coded numbers (`@+id/idname` in XML and `R.id.idname` in code).

Comment: As i said i'm completely new to programming, so i don't know almost anything. So... i should replace your comments in the code with the switch?

Comment: Yes. Both ´onCheckedChanged` calls `updateDate()`. Replace the comments with the switch statements and use `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` (instead `checkedIdSmoke`). I added a recommendation for startes...

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look for it later. If I wanted to add more "questions",do i only have to add the final RadioGroup etc thing and the switch?

Comment: Should be pretty trivial. When the two groups work, just add another one to the layout (I assume your XML file), add the checked listener to that group and finally add the calculation code (switch statement) in `updateDate()`. But again, if you're a fresh starter, you better learn basics of Java first.

Comment: Is the book Java for Dummies (5th edition) a good book to start with?

Comment: I really can't tell. It might be a (good) start for absolute beginners. Personally, when I started, I searched the web for "learning Java" or "Java tutorials" and picked the most detailed ones (I started with C++ but I wouldn't recommend that ;-). Just search the web and you will find a lot of "How to start programming" threads out there.